# How to change location of Google Earth Engine control?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to have the layer selection on the left instead of on the right, because on SplitPanel, the left map's layer selector gets hidden unless you wipe all the way to the right. I know that it is possible to just hide all controls and come up with my own controls, but I kind of like the controls google came up with and they also have quite some extra functionality regarding visualization on top of layer selection. For this reason, I'd like just to change the style of the layer selector. I imagine that if I right just the correct thing as a style, for the correct element, I could achieve that. As of now, I don't know what is the element I need to change the style of, nor do I know what style I should apply.

Here's some code to get 2 linked maps:

```
var splitPanel = ui.SplitPanel({
  firstPanel: ui.Map(),
  secondPanel: ui.Map(),
  wipe: true,
  style: {stretch: 'both'}
});
ui.root.widgets().reset([splitPanel]);
```

Any suggestions?